# Failures in Event Grid

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I have a Azure function which gets XML files and sends it to Event Grid after splitting XML based on batch size. There is another Event Grid Trigger function which gets this message from and does the processing and continues the flow of application. For large xml files also it is working as expected.

But sometimes I get an error on intermittent basic. When I analyze the issue, I see failure in the event grid. If I reprocess the same file again it works. So it is not the issue with the file I am processing.

As per the logs I am getting error message as below for the line of code which send message to event grid.

Is it possible that this happening due to some limitations of event grid but from error message it says `no such host is known`? How i can troubleshoot this. What may be the reason for the failures.

```
 System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (No such host is known.)
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No such host is known.
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): No such host is known.
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at PwC.Bos.Al.Common.Data.Service.CallHttpClientFactory.MyService.GetPage(String _data, String URL, String ContentType, HttpMethod methodType, Dictionary`2 headers)
```

Comment: so you have two Azure Functions both Event Grid triggered. `User->Grid1->F1->Grid2->F2`. Where do you get this error? Can you post the code where you catch this exception?

Comment: Are you trying to implement a *FanOut/FanIn* pattern via the Azure Event Grid? (something like the durable functions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp#fan-in-out)

Comment: Azure function Timer trigger(reads files from SFTP and does batching)->Event grid subscription->Received by another Azure function(Event grid trigger)-> sends to event grid different subscription. Error comes in intermittent in either 1st or 2nd Azure function. We use same event grid with different subscription. Using HttpClient we send it to event grid topic endpoint. So error mentioned is for this.

Comment: Any updates on the solution, im facing the same issue when i updated the package